# AngularJS - Abort previous request

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm trying to abort the previous request if the user makes a new request. I wrote the code below, but requests are still running in parallel. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**Controller**

```
AppControllers.controller('HomeController',
    ['$scope', 'Services', '$q', function($scope, Services, $q) {

    var canceler = $q.defer();

    $scope.model = {};

    $scope.find = function(id) {
      canceler.resolve();
      canceler = $q.defer();
      Services.find(id, canceler).get().$promise.then(function(result) {
        $scope.model = result;
      });
    };

}]);
```

**Services**

```
AppServices.factory("Services", ['$resource', function($resource) {

  var factory = {};
  var serviceBase = 'https://localhost/';

  factory.find = function(id, canceler) {
    return $resource(serviceBase + 'api/find/:Id', {Id: id}, {
      get: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: false,
        timeout: canceler.promise
      }
    });
  };

  return factory;

}]);
```

Comment: can you try this way : http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/24/canceling-http-requests-in-angularjs.aspx

Comment: You can refer to this post.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404579/angular-js-cancel-http-call-before-calling-a-new-http

Comment: You can refer to this old post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404579/angular-js-cancel-http-call-before-calling-a-new-http . plnkr demo also given in it.

Comment: But a new Canceler is created in the above code.

Comment: which version of angular you are using?

Comment: Tested with versions 1.3.2 and 1.3.15

Comment: Can you create a plnkr for this?

Comment: There is a pull request in the backlog that fixes this, but it hasn't been committed: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/11035

Comment: Thank you, tasseKATT. I replaced resource by $http and is now working.