# How to interrupt a series of $http calls in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple $http calls that I perform in a for loop in a controller in angularjs:

```
for(var i = 0; i < links.length;i++) {
 $http // calls a url with "i" as a parameter to retrieve data
}
```

My question is, if I do not want any of these calls to actually continue retrieving data (as it may take a lot of time to retrieve if links.length were say, greater than 100, then how can I make it such that I can click a button to "interrupt"/"stop" any of these $http calls from continuing?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928057/how-to-cancel-an-http-request-in-angularjs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16966971/967859